# C# MVC - Reloading (getting) PartialView losses full URL params on hrefs

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

I'm getting a list from SharePoint and saving it into a C# List. I'm sending that list to the PartialView and doing a Foreach to display the items WITH an edit button that contains their ID.

```
        return PartialView("IRFList", items);

        <h5>@Html.ActionLink("Edit", "Edit", new { id = item.Id }, new { @class = "badge badge-primary editIRFBut" })</h5>
```

The PartialView is loaded on index body.If i click the edit, gets me to edit page, everything works fine. 
I also have a "New Item" button that uses $.post to contact the AddItem controller which creates an item. On success i reload the partial view as such ->

```
        $.ajax({
            url: listUrl,
            type: "GET",
            dataType: "html",
            success: function (data) {
                $('.irfListPartial').html(data);
            },
        });
```

Everything works fine, but there's a problem with my link button after the PartialView reload.

**My url is something like "example.com?SPHostUrl=https.....". When im first loading the index, the edit buttons contain "?SPHostUrl", but when i'm reloading the PartialView they lose that part of the URL.**

I actually need that URL to make calls to sharepoint, my question is....
How can i make sure that my Edit Button link contains ?SPHostUrl in its URL after reloading the partial view ?

***Edit: Updated for easy read based on Shyju's answer.***

```
    public ActionResult IRFList()
    {
        var spContext = SharePointContextProvider.Current.GetSharePointContext(HttpContext);
        List<IRFItem> items = SharepointService.GetItems(spContext);
        ViewBag.SPHostUrl = SharePointContext.GetSPHostUrl(HttpContext.Request).AbsoluteUri;
        return PartialView("IRFList", items);
    }
```

And for the Partial edit button

```
        <h5>@Html.ActionLink("Edit", "Edit", new { id = item.Id, SPHostUrl = ViewBag.SPHostUrl }, new { @class = "badge badge-primary editIRFBut" })</h5>
```

Comment: You either need to send it to your controller and add it to the link parameters or do it on the client before you inject the html into `.irfListPartial`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to pass this querystring item to your action method which returns the partial view result and inside that action method, you will pass it again to the partial view where you will use that to create your edit link `href` value.

Here is a quick example, which uses `ViewBag` to pass the value of `SPHostUrl` parameter to the view. If you have a view model use that to pass the value, instead of ViewBag.

```
public ActionResult ListPartial(string SPHostUrl)
{
    var posts = db.Posts.ToList();
    ViewBag.SPHostUrl = SPHostUrl;
    return PartialView(posts);
}
```

And in your partial view

```
@model List<YourNamespace.Post>
<div>
    @foreach (var item in Model)
    {
        <h4>@item.Title<h4>
        <h5>@Html.ActionLink("Edit", "Edit",
                       new { id = item.Id, SPHostUrl = ViewBag.SPHostUrl },
                       new { @class = "badge badge-primary editIRFBut" }) 
        </h5>    
    }
</div>
```

Now all you have to do is, send the `SPHostUrl` querystring when making the ajax call. To do this, you can again, use the same approach to pass the `SPHostUrl` value to the main view(in which we are loading the partial view result via ajax)

```
public ActionResult Index(string spHostUrl)
{
   ViewBag.SpHostUrl = spHostUrl;
   return View();
}
```

Here again i am using `ViewBag` to pass the data between action method and view. If you have a view model, add a new property to that and use that to pass the parameter value to your view.

Now, in your view, use this ViewBag item when you build the url which is needed for the ajax call. I like to rely on the `Url.Action` method to generate the correct the relative link values to the action method. In the below example, i am calling the Url.Action method inside my razor view and storing the result of that (the url to the action method which returns the partial view) as html5 data attribute value to our container div.

```
<div class="irfListPartial" 
     data-url="@Url.Action("ListPartial",new { spHostUrl=ViewBag.SpHostUrl})">
</div>
```

When razor executes the above code, it will generate HTML markup like below.

```
<div class="irfListPartial" data-url="/Posts/ListPartial"></div>
```

When making the ajax call, all we have to do is to read this `data` attribute value of the div and use that for the ajax call.

```
var $partial = $('.irfListPartial');
var listUrl = $partial.data("url");

$.ajax({
         url: listUrl,               
         success: function (data) {
           $partial.html(data);
         }
});
```

Now as long as your main action method is invoked with the `spHostUrl` querystring, your ajax method will pass that value to your partial view action method which will use that for creating the edit link urls.

Comment: Awesome! Thanks a lot. I only added SPHostUrl = ViewBag.SPHostUrl to my ActionLink for the partial (after setting the ViewBag) and it works (im reloading with ajax get). I didnt know the 2nd arg would add the querystring to be honest.

Once again thanks, worked like a charm ^^.

Edit: Index doesn't need SPHostUrl because the only way to access the page is by clicking a link that already has ?SPHostUrl="link".